# Visual Studio 2022 17.4 indentation behaviour changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The indentation behaviour of Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4 has changed.
Has anyone figured out how to make it behave like it did in 17.3?

I have this typed:

[image]

Then I hit [enter], and I get

[image]

The cursor is now indented, as opposed to being under the 'f' like it used to in previous builds.
If the statement "foo" was a valid statement, then the cursor does not get indented.

Obviously, I could just write perfect code from top to bottom without ever typing an incomplete statement, but I'm just not that good :-/

Comment: Click Tools->option->c#. It may be possible to modify the indented code format.

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT There is no code format option that says something like "indent after invalid statement". The more I think about it, the more I think this is not an intended behaviour.

Comment: Does your project have an `.editorconfig` in it anywhere?

Comment: @Dai No, I do not have any .editorconfig.

Comment: As @user123 below pointed out, it seems like the root of the problem is that the editor uses "smart" tabbing even though I have my settings set to "block".

Comment: For those affected by this, know that a fix is apparently coming
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-174:-C-editor-always-uses-Smar/10195742

Comment: @Patrick thanks for posting that link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worse than that. The option Text Editor->All languages->Tabs->Indenting (or Text Editor->any language->Tabs->Indenting for that matter), which is a radio between None, Block and Smart, is completely botched - in 17.4, no matter what you set there, you get the "smart" behavior. Way to go Micro%$#^.
Btw - upon seeing this, I made the mistake of my life - roll back Visual Studio to the previous version (using the Rollback button in the VS installer) - that fixed the Indenting behavior, but completely reset all of my Visual Studio settings, including colors, everything. Starting with a blank slate. Thank you, thank you, thank you MS.

Answer (score 0):

After my testing, I reproduced your problem, this is a bug.

I suggest you post this to the [dc forums](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio?q=%5BVisual%20Studio%202022%20version%2017.4.1%5D) and attach the relevant link to the question.